# All transactions in the metamask are in expectation

Tags: transactions, metamask, ledger-nano-s

For 4 days I can not make a transactions in Ethereum mainnet. I am trying to buy nft token from Ledjer hardware wallet. And if before I was sent to the Ledjer Live app to open a "bridge" to the app, now it is not happening. I've tried doing a reset of the metamask wallet, sending a transaction with a custom nonce , putting above gas. Nothing works.[image]

Ledjer's support doesn't say much about that. I really need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there was a chrome browser update which caused this issue but that was a while back. Maybe try using a different browser like Brave or Firefox. That could help narrow down the issue if it still persists.